# Why is the "-wise" suffix popular in computing only in the expression "bitwise"?

Tags: etymology

In computing, one particular use of the *-wise* suffix is very common: *bitwise*.

It seems that, as a suffix, *-wise* it is not currently used very often (I recall only *clockwise* and *likewise* in common parlance), not even for the very closely related term *bytewise*.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bit-wise) claims the first known usage for *bitwise* is from 1896, and that it would be related to *horse bits* (the part which the horse bites; unrelated to Shannon's adoption of *bit*, related to *binary digit*, in 1948). I could not find the actual usage, nor when did it transition from horses to computing.

Also, *bitwise* seems an exceptional case; for instance, I never heard *filewise* (instead, *file-by-file*) nor *functionwise* (instead, *per function*).

Is it known when and why *bitwise* became related to computing, and why no other *-wise* term became popular?

Comment: Don't overlook [**stepwise**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/stepwise). Note that a computer **bit** is unrelated to that part of the horse harness. It is an elision of "binary digit" and was an apt coinage for a "small amount". There are also two meanings of **-wise**. One is "knowing" which would apply to the horse's bit: the horse is accustomed to it. The other is "in the fashion of" which applies to the computing word bitwise, meaning bit by bit.

Comment: bytewise is certainly in use. Characterwise is also found sometimes (although it and wordwise have other meanings).

Comment: Also note that "wise" as a suffix/morphological unit meaning "in relation to" is common, e.g. jobwise, personality wise. http://www.onestopenglish.com/skills/vocabulary/macmillan-dictionary-resources/your-english/word-grammar/your-english-word-grammar-wise/550157.article

Comment: "Why" questions like this are always problematic. Word and phrase popularity is like clothing styles, you can't really explain why they happen, they're usually just happenstance.

Comment: Sometimes a word gets used and sticks, sometimes it doesn't. Sometimes it starts a trend, sometimes it's just an outlier.